# WIll the magento 2 extension works with magento 1?

Tags: magento2

The question is straight forward.
I am developing an extension for magento 2. Will it be compatible with magento 1 as well? 
Is it wise to develop for magento 2? Or should I develop for magento 1 such that i can cover a wider range of existing magento users?

Comment: NO! It will not work with Magento 1

Comment: Magento 2 extension is not compactible with magento 1.

Comment: So Is it right for me to develop for magento 2? Or should i develop for magento 1 so that i will be able to cover lot of the existing magento users? @rak

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 and Magento 1 are not compatible with each other. If an extension is made in Magento 1 it won't be compatible with Magento 2 and vice versa.

The main reason for it is the structure of both. Magento 2 has wide changes in structure the code is being done. In Magento 2 has changed coding conventions introduction to the namespace, di, plugins, events, etc.Introduction to symphony.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks :) I want to develop an extension for magento to integrate with our product. Should I develop for magento 2 or for magento 1 keeping in mind the number of magento users. I see there are very less number of extension in magento 2 marketplace.  What would you suggest?