# Magento 1 backward compatibility with magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool

[Magento 2 modules are not compatible with magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160717/will-the-magento-2-extension-works-with-magento-1)

Now, since there still is a large number of deployments using magento 1:

**Is there a  convenient way to generate magento 1 compatible modules from a magento 2 module ?**

There is a [magento 1->2 migration tool](https://github.com/magento/code-migration), so this would be the reverse process.

Comment: Magento 1 extension is not compactible with magento 2

Comment: Thanks, this is my whole point ! My question is: is there a convenient way to handle this issue ?

Comment: As an update, I found out that Magento 1 End Of Life was announced for June 2020. Hence this might not be an issue for much longer